# Homework Question for a 15 year old

Tags: induction, recreational-mathematics

My younger brother(age: 14 years 7 months) and his classmates were given a set of eight questions by his class-teacher, which included the following two questions:

**(i)** *Find, if you can, the fallacy in the following proof(!):*

**Claim:"any two positive integers are equal"**

**Proof:**
Suppose, $A_n$ be the statement

> if $a$ and $b$ are any two positive integers,such that, $\max(a,b)=n$, then $a=b$

Suppose $A_r$ to be true. Let $a$ and $b$ be any two positive integers, such that $\max(a,b)=r+1$. Consider the two integers, $c=a-1$, $d=b-1$; then $\max(c,d)=r$. Hence $c=d$, for we are assuming $A_r$ to be true. It follows $a=b$; hence $A_{(r+1)}$ is true. *$A_1$ is obviously true, for if $\max(a,b)=1$, since*  $a,b$ are by hypothesis positive integers, they must be both equal to $1$. Therefore, by mathematical induction , $A_n$ is true for every $n$. Now,if $a$ and $b$ are any two positive integers whatsoever, denote $\max(a,b)$ by $r$. Since $A_n$ has been shown to be true for every $n$, in particular, $A_r$ is true. Hence $a=b$.

**What I have done:**

If $a=1$,$b=1$, then $c=d=0$. So, $\max(c,d)$ is not defined, because $0$ is not a positive integer. So, $A_1$ is false, and hence, our basis step in the induction process suffers a heavy blow, which shatters the foundation upon which the palace is built, consequently bringing about utter destruction of the palace itself.

**What's my problem:**

Is there any simpler way to convince my brother how to proceed regarding disproving this claim?

Comment: @abstract Close. $A_1$ is _true_, not false. The error is in the inductive step. When you consider the two numbers $c=a-1,d=b-1$, _there is no guarantee that these will be positive_. For example, $1$ and $2$ have $\max\{1,2\}=2=1+1=r+1$ but $c=a-1=0$ is not a positive integer, so you cannot apply the induction hypothesis.

Comment: @ NotNotLogical: right you are. I did not go any further than a=1,b=1. I should have been more careful in identifying the exact problem-posing region.

Comment: To write subscripts, use `$A_n$`: $A_n$

Comment: @NotNotLogical Would you mind converting your comment into an answer, so that is may be removed from the unanswered que?

Answer (score 0):

Close. $A_1$ is true, not false. The error is in the inductive step. When you consider the two numbers $c=a−1,d=b−1$, there is no guarantee that these will be positive. For example, $1$ and $2$ have $\max\{1,2\}=2=1+1=r+1$ but $c=a−1=0$ is not a positive integer, so you cannot apply the induction hypothesis.